# Nodejs/Puppeteer - How to use page.evaluate

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I know is a noob question, but I want to know when I should use page.evaluate

I also know the documentation exists, but I still do not understand

Can anybody give me an explanation about how and when to use this function when creating a scraper with puppeteer?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, it is important to understand that there are two main environments:

- Node.js (Puppeteer) Environment
- Page DOM Environment

You should use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) when you are seeking to interact with the page directly in the page DOM environment by passing a function and returning a `<`[`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description)`<`[`Serializable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description)`>>` which resolves to the return value of the passed function.

Otherwise, if you do not use `page.evaluate()`, you will be dealing with elements as an [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) object in the Node.js (Puppeteer) environment.

**Example Usage:**

```
const example = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('example');
  const result = [];

  document.title = 'New Title';

  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    result.push(elements[i].textContent);
  }

  return JSON.stringify(result);
});
```

**See the simplified diagram below:**

[image: Puppeteer page.evaluate() Diagram]

Comment: How do I have access to this document variable? We don't even declare that :0

Comment: @JoseLeles: the function you pass to `page.evaluate` is evaluated inside the Page DOM environment, essentially as if you'd opened a developer tools console and run the code from there. There, `document` is available - but if you tried to reach outside and use something else from the rest of the Puppeteer script, it wouldn't be there.