# How can I use session storage in a Puppeteer script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, puppeteer

I am trying to collect the encounter id from a Puppeteer script that opens a browser. I run these scripts in AWS synthetic canaries. It does not run, the error reads:

> sessionStorage is not defined Stack

This is the code I use

```
let data = sessionStorage.getItem('aw-encounter-id');
```

Comment: Please post the code that exemplifies the _minimum reproducibility_ of the error (remove all irrelevant code). You can also run Canaries locally with [synthetics-canaries](https://github.com/AnthumChris/synthetics-canaries).

Comment: You need to set an item before you retrieve it. Also you might want to switch to localStorage instead. localStorage allow to save key/value pairs in the browser. Storage is shared between all tabs and windows from the same origin. The data does not expire. It remains after the browser restart and even OS reboot.

Comment: Are you running `sessionStorage.getItem('aw-encounter-id');` in the webpage itself, or in node? If in node, you may want to read up on the differences: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52046312

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The browser (Puppeteer) needs to support sessionStorage.  This article may help:

https://newbedev.com/puppeteer-how-to-store-a-session-including-cookies-page-state-local-storage-etc-and-continue-later

According to that, it might work if you initialize passing a data dir:

```
   puppeteer.launch({userDataDir: '/tmp/myChromeSession'});
```

Comment: The script may need to obtain the path from the [AWS Lambda env vars](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime)

Comment: not elaborated answer, posting just a link doesn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using `page.evaluate()`

```js
const aeid = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('aw-encounter-id');
});
```

It is working for me at least.